# What is wrong with my C# code? Possibly too many brackets?

Tags: c#, syntax-error

sorry for the poor title, as it shows I seem to have a massive error with my code, all was going well until I changed the method of loading data from a previous screen (changing it from loading xml to txt).  After seeing all these errors I assumed it was the code I had written so I removed it and it still won't work.

After searching for an answer in previous questions people seem to think it's an extra bracket or semicolon, but to my best effort (even though my eyes aren't amazing) I can't seem to find the problem.

Thank you in advance.  I appreciate it and although this might seem like a silly question, I just can't seem to find the issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace Planet_of_fightcraft_final_build
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for PartySelectionScreen.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class PartySelectionScreen : Window
{
    public PartySelectionScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // When the partySelectionScreen is loaded
    // it will deserialize and read the NameData.xml file
    // and will populate the charName and charStats textboxes
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NameSavingInformation));
        FileStream read = new FileStream("NameData.xml",
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

        NameSavingInformation nameInfo = (NameSavingInformation)sr.Deserialize(read);
        charNameTextBox.Text = nameInfo.GeneratedName;

        // Setting the values of the user characters stats 
        // ucs = user class stats
        userClassStats ucs = new userClassStats();

        /*------Character Stats------*/
        ucs.H = 200;
        ucs.AP = 75;
        ucs.CA = 125;
        ucs.S = 100;
        //---------------------------//

        string health = "Health: " + ucs.H;
        string attackPower = "Attack Power: " + ucs.AP;
        string criticalAttack = "Critical Power: " + ucs.CA;
        string speed = "Speed: " + ucs.S;
        /*------Character Stats------*/

        string nl = "\n \n";
        charStatsTextBox.Text =
            health + nl +
            attackPower + nl +
            criticalAttack + nl +
            speed;
    }



    // This sets a limit on how many party memebers can be added into the listbox at one time
    public int limit = 10;
    public string limitMsg = "You have reached the maxmimum amount of party memebers, please delete some and try again.";

    private void generatePartyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Array of party members that can be randomly generated into the listbox.
        string[] partyMembers =
        {
            "Barbarian",
            "Elf",
            "Wizard",
            "Dragon",
            "Knight"
        };

        Random r = new Random();


        // This checks to see if there are allready existing party members in the list box, if so it will
        // prompt the user asking them for confirmation that they want to re - generate the list.
        // If yes it will clear all the items and re add new ones.
        if (partyMembersListBox.Items.Count <= limit)
        {
            partyMembersListBox.Items.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
            }

        }



    }

    // This will allow the user to edit the stats of the selected party memeber from the listbox
    private void editStatsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (partyMembersListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Barbarian")
        {
            BStatsEditing bStatsEditing = new BStatsEditing();
            bStatsEditing.Show();
        }
        else if (partyMembersListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Elf")
        {
            EStatsEditing eStatsEditing = new EStatsEditing();
            eStatsEditing.Show();
        }
    }

    // The user can choose their team without random generation.
    // this will check to see if the count of items in the list box is less than the limit
    // if so it will manualy add the - character, else it will show a messagebox informing them
    // they have reached the maximum amount of characters and must delete some.
    private void addBarbarianButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (partyMembersListBox.Items.Count < limit)
        {
            // bc = Barbarian Character.
            string bc = "Barbarian";

            partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(bc);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(limitMsg);
        }

    }


    // The user can choose their team without random generation.
    // this will check to see if the count of items in the list box is less than the limit
    // if so it will manualy add the - character, else it will show a messagebox informing them
    // they have reached the maximum amount of characters and must delete some.
    private void addElfButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (partyMembersListBox.Items.Count < limit)
        {
            // ec = Elf Character.
            string ec = "Elf";

            partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(ec);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(limitMsg);
        }
    }


    // The user can choose their team without random generation.
    // this will check to see if the count of items in the list box is less than the limit
    // if so it will manualy add the - character, else it will show a messagebox informing them
    // they have reached the maximum amount of characters and must delete some.
    private void addWizardButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (partyMembersListBox.Items.Count < limit)
        {
            // wc = Wizard Character.
            string wc = "Wizard";

            partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(wc);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(limitMsg);
        }
    }


    // The user can choose their team without random generation.
    // this will check to see if the count of items in the list box is less than the limit
    // if so it will manualy add the - character, else it will show a messagebox informing them
    // they have reached the maximum amount of characters and must delete some.
    private void addDragonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (partyMembersListBox.Items.Count < limit)
        {
            //dc = Dragon Character.
            string dc = "Dragon";

            partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(dc);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(limitMsg);
        }
    }


    // The user can choose their team without random generation.
    // this will check to see if the count of items in the list box is less than the limit
    // if so it will manualy add the - character, else it will show a messagebox informing them
    // they have reached the maximum amount of characters and must delete some.
    private void addKnightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (partyMembersListBox.Items.Count < limit)
        {
            //kc = Knight Character.
            string kc = "Knight";

            partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(kc);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(limitMsg);
        }
    }


    // This allows the user to delete one or more chosen characters from the listbox.
    private void deletePartyMember_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.partyMembersListBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            this.partyMembersListBox.Items.RemoveAt(this.partyMembersListBox.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }

    // This will save the current party members to the PartyData.txt file
    private void savePartyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("PartyData.txt");
        foreach (var item in partyMembersListBox.Items)
        {
            SaveFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        SaveFile.Close();
    }

    // This will search for the PartyData.txt file 
    // if it is found it will load the party data and populate the partyMembersListBox with said data
    // if it cannot be found a messagebox will inform the user and prompt them to create a new party.
    private void loadPartyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists("PartyData.txt"))
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("PartyData.txt");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to find existing party data, please create a new party!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your class is ending right after your Window_Loaded event.  I doubt that is what you want.

Comment: Look at the examples section on this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) (right at the bottom) for proper usage of the stream writer

Comment: Thankyou so much cant believe i didnt spot that! and also thankyou for the resources will definitally give it a read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've closed your class prematurely. Depending on your editor, you chould have a red squiggly line just before your `Window_Loaded` remove one close bracket just before you declare your `int limit`. This is the updated code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace Planet_of_fightcraft_final_build
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for PartySelectionScreen.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class PartySelectionScreen : Window
{
    public PartySelectionScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // When the partySelectionScreen is loaded
    // it will deserialize and read the NameData.xml file
    // and will populate the charName and charStats textboxes
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NameSavingInformation));
        FileStream read = new FileStream("NameData.xml",
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

        NameSavingInformation nameInfo = (NameSavingInformation)sr.Deserialize(read);
        charNameTextBox.Text = nameInfo.GeneratedName;

        // Setting the values of the user characters stats 
        // ucs = user class stats
        userClassStats ucs = new userClassStats();

        /*------Character Stats------*/
        ucs.H = 200;
        ucs.AP = 75;
        ucs.CA = 125;
        ucs.S = 100;
        //---------------------------//

        string health = "Health: " + ucs.H;
        string attackPower = "Attack Power: " + ucs.AP;
        string criticalAttack = "Critical Power: " + ucs.CA;
        string speed = "Speed: " + ucs.S;
        /*------Character Stats------*/

        string nl = "\n \n";
        charStatsTextBox.Text =
            health + nl +
            attackPower + nl +
            criticalAttack + nl +
            speed;
    }



    // This sets a limit on how many party memebers can be added into the listbox at one time
    public int limit = 10;
    public string limitMsg = "You have reached the maxmimum amount of party memebers, please delete some and try again.";

    private void generatePartyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Array of party members that can be randomly generated into the listbox.
        string[] partyMembers =
        {
            "Barbarian",
            "Elf",
            "Wizard",
            "Dragon",
            "Knight"
        };

        Random r = new Random();


        // This checks to see if there are allready existing party members in the list box, if so it will
        // prompt the user asking them for confirmation that they want to re - generate the list.
        // If yes it will clear all the items and re add new ones.
        if (partyMembersListBox.Items.Count <= limit)
        {
            partyMembersListBox.Items.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(partyMembers[r.Next(0, 4)]);
            }

        }



    }

    // This will allow the user to edit the stats of the selected party memeber from the listbox
    private void editStatsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (partyMembersListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Barbarian")
        {
            BStatsEditing bStatsEditing = new BStatsEditing();
            bStatsEditing.Show();
        }
        else if (partyMembersListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Elf")
        {
            EStatsEditing eStatsEditing = new EStatsEditing();
            eStatsEditing.Show();
        }
    }

    // The user can choose their team without random generation.
    // this will check to see if the count of items in the list box is less than the limit
    // if so it will manualy add the - character, else it will show a messagebox informing them
    // they have reached the maximum amount of characters and must delete some.
    private void addBarbarianButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (partyMembersListBox.Items.Count < limit)
        {
            // bc = Barbarian Character.
            string bc = "Barbarian";

            partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(bc);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(limitMsg);
        }

    }


    // The user can choose their team without random generation.
    // this will check to see if the count of items in the list box is less than the limit
    // if so it will manualy add the - character, else it will show a messagebox informing them
    // they have reached the maximum amount of characters and must delete some.
    private void addElfButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (partyMembersListBox.Items.Count < limit)
        {
            // ec = Elf Character.
            string ec = "Elf";

            partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(ec);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(limitMsg);
        }
    }


    // The user can choose their team without random generation.
    // this will check to see if the count of items in the list box is less than the limit
    // if so it will manualy add the - character, else it will show a messagebox informing them
    // they have reached the maximum amount of characters and must delete some.
    private void addWizardButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (partyMembersListBox.Items.Count < limit)
        {
            // wc = Wizard Character.
            string wc = "Wizard";

            partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(wc);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(limitMsg);
        }
    }


    // The user can choose their team without random generation.
    // this will check to see if the count of items in the list box is less than the limit
    // if so it will manualy add the - character, else it will show a messagebox informing them
    // they have reached the maximum amount of characters and must delete some.
    private void addDragonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (partyMembersListBox.Items.Count < limit)
        {
            //dc = Dragon Character.
            string dc = "Dragon";

            partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(dc);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(limitMsg);
        }
    }


    // The user can choose their team without random generation.
    // this will check to see if the count of items in the list box is less than the limit
    // if so it will manualy add the - character, else it will show a messagebox informing them
    // they have reached the maximum amount of characters and must delete some.
    private void addKnightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (partyMembersListBox.Items.Count < limit)
        {
            //kc = Knight Character.
            string kc = "Knight";

            partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(kc);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(limitMsg);
        }
    }


    // This allows the user to delete one or more chosen characters from the listbox.
    private void deletePartyMember_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.partyMembersListBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            this.partyMembersListBox.Items.RemoveAt(this.partyMembersListBox.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }

    // This will save the current party members to the PartyData.txt file
    private void savePartyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("PartyData.txt");
        foreach (var item in partyMembersListBox.Items)
        {
            SaveFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        SaveFile.Close();
    }

    // This will search for the PartyData.txt file 
    // if it is found it will load the party data and populate the partyMembersListBox with said data
    // if it cannot be found a messagebox will inform the user and prompt them to create a new party.
    private void loadPartyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists("PartyData.txt"))
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("PartyData.txt");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                partyMembersListBox.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to find existing party data, please create a new party!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly thankyou so much, cant believe i missed that!

Comment: @Ambitiousmilky My pleasure :-). Please mark all your answers as correct for future reference, and also maybe use something like [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/) for syntax highlighting. It helps as a new developer, and welcome to the world of .NET :D